# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph in figure caption

Tags: badness

I think the source of the error `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph' in the MWE is insufficiency of text.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{Interface among Processor, RAM and TPM in a Hybrid System}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting long words in a narrow column can be tricky, you could help tex a little:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
\caption
[Interface among Processor, RAM and TPM in a Hybrid System]
{\protect\raggedright Interface among Processor, RAM and TPM in a Hybrid System}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It did work. But what was the problem Latex facing earlier?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock it isn't really a problem, but just warning about the output: it cannot hyphenate those words and the text width is small so it had to stretch white space beyond acceptable limits so it warns about that. `\raggedright` tells it to give up trying to justify the right margin so that white space is allowed to stretch on the right, so then the problem, goes away and it doesn't have to stretch inter-word space