# Is it OK to ignore Underfull \hbox errors? I attempted, but it did not wok. I use textpos and ragged2e

Tags: xetex, memoir, textpos, ragged2e

I tried to solve by middle of the following questions:

- [ragged2e: "newcommands" option produces "underfull \hbox" warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17659/ragged2e-newcommands-option-produces-underfull-hbox-warnings),
- [Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph in figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241632/underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-in-figure-caption)
- and [Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275305/underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-longtable), but it was unsuccessful.

I use the class `memoir`, the packages `polyglossia`, `textpos` and `ragged2e`. I added `\linebreak`. I compile in XeLaTeX. I use Linux and macOS.

I am not sure if it is OK to igonre the errors of `Underful \hbox` because they are very common, but someone counselled me to keep my document clean and free of errors, economic and optimised.

Here is the small code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands, dvipsnames]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\definecolor{solitudeblue3}{HTML}{E5E9F0}

\newfontfamily\alegreya{Alegreya}[Path = ./fontes/,
  FontFace = {xb}{n}  {* Black},
  FontFace = {xb}{it} {* Black Italic},
  UprightFont       = * Regular,
  ItalicFont        = * Regular Italic,
  BoldFont          = * Bold,
  BoldItalicFont    = * Bold Italic,
  NFSSFamily        = alegreyaot
]

\newcommand{\ProfCurso}[1]
{
    \alegreya{\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont \color{solitudeblue3} #1}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{textblock*}{15cm}(4cm, 15cm) 
    \RaggedLeft 
    \ProfCurso{Profª Lígia Brezolin} 
    \linebreak
    \ProfCurso{Administração do Sistema de Informação II}
  \end{textblock*}

  \maketitle

\end{document}
```

### Update

`\maketitle` is also accused of Underfull hbox due to `ragged2e`.

Comment: General answer: **Never** ignore errors and **try your best** to fix the errors as well as to avoid warnings.

Comment: `Over[under]ful \hbox` is a common warning. Ignoring them doesn't cause much harm. However it will be much better if you can avoid it :)

Comment: Don't use \RaggedLeft there, use \raggedleft instead.

Comment: My impression is that you want to use `titlepage`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand.

Comment: @egreg said that you should use the `titlepage` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `titlingpage` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{solitudeblue3}{HTML}{E5E9FF}

\newfontfamily\alegreya{Alegreya}[
  %Path = ./fontes/,
  FontFace = {xb}{n}  {*-Black},
  FontFace = {xb}{it} {*-BlackItalic},
  UprightFont       = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont        = *-Italic,
  BoldFont          = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont    = *-BoldItalic,
  NFSSFamily        = alegreyaot
]

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}

\vspace*{\stretch{3}}

\fontsize{15pt}{24pt}\alegreya

\raggedleft
%\color{solitudeblue3}
Profª Lígia Brezolin \\
Administração do Sistema de Informação II

\vspace*{\stretch{2}}

\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

I commented out the `\color` instruction as that color is unreadable on white background.

[image]

Comment: I was going to update, but I have tested with your codes, it worked and overfull has disappeared. I also have just discovered that `\pagestyle{fancyheads}` was caused by overfull, causing error to this textpos. because I have changed the layout measures to make page wider. I will correct.